# Weird behaviour when enabling interrupts for CTC mode onTimer0 on ATtiny85

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupt, avr, attiny

I'm using an ATtiny85 for a simple IR project built on C (an IR remote for a DSLR camera). I generated a 38.4 kHz square signal using Timer 0 in CTC mode and set the output to toggle PB0 every time the timer reaches it's max value `OCRA`. I wanted to use the interrupts generated by the timer 0 compare unit to count the number of cycles that it has generated, since the counter reaches it's max two times to generate a full period of the 38.4 kHz square wave, counting two interrupts should indicate a full cycle. **The problem**: I noticed that every time I called the `sei()` function to enable global interrupts, the generated square wave would deform and the ISR associated would never be called. Using an oscilloscope I checked the generated wave on PB0:

- **Not calling sei() function during setup:** The generated square wave looks as expected.
  [image: working-example]
- **Calling sei() during setup:** The generated square wave has some longer pulses.
  [image]

### How did I test this?

I implemented the following test-code that configures Timer 0 as previously described and toggles PB1 every time an interrupt associated with the compare unit of timer 0 is detected:

- `main.h`

```c
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#define __AVR_ATtiny85__
#define F_CPU 8000000UL

#endif
```

- `main.c`

```c
#include "main.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

int main(void)
{
    cli();
    DDRB |= _BV(PB0) | _BV(PB1);
    PORTB &= ~_BV(PB1);
    // Set general register to sync mode for configuration
    GTCCR |= _BV(TSM) | _BV(PSR0);
    // Default registers
    TCCR0A = 0; 
    TCCR0B = 0;
    TCNT0 = 0;
    TCCR0A |= _BV(COM0A0) | _BV(WGM01); // Set toggle on match and CTC mode
    TCCR0B |= _BV(CS00); // internal clock no-prescaling
    OCR0A |= 12; // For app 38,8kHz
    TIMSK |= _BV(OCIE0A);
    // Enable timer
    GTCCR &= ~_BV(TSM) & ~_BV(PSR0);
    // Enable global interrupts
    sei();  
    while(1);

}
// Demo interrupt service routine
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect){
    PORTB ^= _BV(PB1);
}
```

To compile the code I used `avr-gcc` as follows:

```
avr-gcc main.c -o main.elf -Wall -Wextra
```

No warnings where raised from the compiler. Then I used `avr-objcopy` to get the hex file:

```
avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .text -j .data main.elf main.hex
```

Finally I programmed the IC using avrdude:

```
avrdude -p t85 -c usbtiny -B 125kHz -U flash:w:main.hex
```

The fuses are:

```
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FF, H:DF, L:62)
```

### What have I tried?

**- Setting the SREG register manually:**

Replacing the `sei()` line for:

```c
SREG |= 1 << 7;
```

[image: sreg_text]
Does something, but still doesn't work. The generated square wave looks better, but is not as expected and the ISR is not doing anything to the PB1.

**- Replacing the ISR operation:** I though maybe the port operation was taking to much time, but replacing it with `_NOP();` had no effect on the weird behaviour on the generated square wave.

**-Tried with other IC:** I had another ATtiny85 laying around and behaves the same. Maybe I have two defective ICs?

I don't know if I configured something wrong or when I enable the interrupts using `sei()` the IC is getting bombarded with interruptions and not working properly?

Thanks in advance for any tip or reply!

Comment: _Caveat:_ I don't know AVR, so just guessing ... Chances are that you _are_ being bombarded with interrupts. From: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/using-timer0-compb-vect You may want to do: `TIMSK |= _BV(OCIE0A);` --> `TIMSK = _BV(OCIE0A);`??? Other things: Do you need to set `OCR0B` (since you set `TCCR0B`)? Do you need to set `OCIE0B` in `TIMSK0`? Or, is that just because the link is using two timers? You could do (e.g.) `++isr_counter` in the ISR (it should be `volatile`). Then, monitor it in the main `while` loop. I bet it's increasing far too fast.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just tried setting the interrupt mask with `TIMSK = _BV(OCIE0A)` but sadly I'm still getting weird artifacts on the generated square wave. In my case, TCCR0B corresponds to the register B of the Timer 0. On the example provided, the author set Timer 0, but used both of the provided compare units to get two different interrupts one when timer 0 reaches `OCR0A` and one when reaches `OCR0B`.  I tried using the main `while loop` to test the ISR, got similar results, it seems that the interrupt is not being set or is not calling the ISR.

Comment: 10us period = 100kHz, not 38.4kHz. So how does that look "as expected"?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. The scope resolution was set to 10us, this means 10us per division, my signal takes roughly 2.6 squares to complete a full cycle,  so 2.6*10us = 26us that equals a frequency of 38,4 kHz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `#define __AVR_ATtiny85__`

Don't fiddle with internal macros of the tool chain.  Instead...

> `avr-gcc main.c -o main.elf -Wall -Wextra`

...compile and link with `-mmcu=attiny85`. If that option is missing, the link stage won't link against the startup code `crtattiny85.o`, and setting some macro won't fix that.

Notice that **without startup code, there won't be a vector table** either.  This means when an IRQ triggers and the hardware jumps to respective IRQ vector, the code will end up somewhere else in the program but not in the ISR code.

Moreover, without `-mmcu=` the compiler will use the wrong AVR architecture: In avr-gcc, ATtiny85 is `avr25` whereas the default (without `-mmcu=`) is `avr2`. See [avr-gcc machine dependent options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.5.0/gcc/AVR-Options.html).

---

Some improvements not related to the problem:

- `OCR0A |= 12;` is odd, just `OCR0A = 12;`.  Same for some other SFRs like configuring Timer 0 using `TCCR0A/B`: in almost all cases, you wans to set *all* bits there, not just or-ing some bits.
- Some AVRs like ATtiny85 support toggling I/O pins by writing a one to PINx register: `PINB = 1 << PB1` to toggle PortB1 instead of `PORTB ^= _BV(PB1)`.
- avrdude understands ELF format, so you need not build iHEX, you can flash `main.elf` directly, cf. [documentation](https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_3.html#Option-Descriptions) of option `-U`.
- It might be better to define `F_CPU` on the command line by means of `-DF_CPU=8000000`.  That way it's ensured that each module has the macro handy.

Comment: Great catch. Interrupt is likely ending up back at the start of the program, which is then resetting the timer registers back to zeros before again setting them to desired values which then ends up again back at the start of the program to repeat- which matches the waveform seen.

Comment: Thanks! After setting the missing `-mmcu=attiny85` the problem was solved!

Also thanks for the tips! Not sure how I didn't notice that I was setting the `OCR0A` register with an OR op haha. Again thanks! Marking this as the solution

Comment: Also don't forget to remove that `#define __AVR_ATtiny85__` from main.h. avr-gcc will set it for you provided `-mmcu=attiny85`.